# Angular2 HttpClient Not Mapping to Interface

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api

I'm working with Angular and an ASP.NET WebApi. I am trying to pass an object from the API to Angular and map it to an interface I have defined with Typescript.

Here is my TypeScript interface:

```
export interface IUser {
    userId: number;
    username: string;
}
```

Here is my object on the backend:

```
public class UserDto
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the call from my User service:

```
get(userId: number): Observable<IUser> {
    return this._http.get<IUser>(this._getUrl);
}
```

Here is where I am trying to use the object that I get back:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this._userService.get(1).subscribe(data => { 
        this.user = { 
          userId: data.userId, username: data.username 
        };
      });
  }
```

The function from the controller that I am calling on the API:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Get")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, _userLogic.Get(1));
    }
```

And here is the _userLogic.Get() function, in case you need it. (Just testing things, dummy data)..

```
    public UserDto Get(int userId)
    {
        UserDto d = new UserDto()
        {
            UserId = 1,
            Username = "test"
        };

        return d;
    }
```

My problem is that the object that I am getting back is not actually mapping to my IUser Typescript interface. Below is what I see when I am debugging:

[image]

It's completely ignoring (or skipping?) the mapping piece it seems and is just returning the object as is from the WebApi.

This means that data.userId is undefined. However, if I do data.UserId, it works. This is not ideal though because I am not getting the benefits of mapping to the Typescript object (intellisense, mostly...).

Any ideas? I am completely stumped.

**EDIT**
Per Mike Tung's suggestion below.. still doesn't work this way either.

[image]

**EDIT**
I finally got this working. I needed to add the following lines to the WebApiConfig to serialize my objects properly from the WebApi. Thanks for the help.

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new 
          System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

Comment: The data was serialized with PascalCase, not camelCase. What you get back in Angular is `UserId` whereas what you need is `userId`.

Comment: Instead of using properties in .NET, try manually writing a POCO class with getters and setters. Check whether it is working this way.

Comment: @HarryNinh So you're suggesting that I make the properties on my C# UserDto class camelCase? I suppose that would work. Isn't that against C# conventions though?

Comment: @ArjunPanicker UserDto is a POCO class with getters and setters.

Comment: @halterdev No I don't. Keep PascalCase on C# code and camelCase on client-side Javascript code as per conventions. Somewhere between the two you must serialize POCOs to JSON right, that's where you can plug in the settings. If you didn't know anything about that, I suggest looking for how to configure settings for Newtonsoft.Json (which I believe still is the default JSON Serializer of ASP.NET)

Comment: Are you working with .net core or .net framework?

Comment: @HarryNinh .NET Framework. I got it though, your previous reply helped. I needed to add serialization to convert to camelCase. I added what I did to my original post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @halterdev that's great!

Answer (score 0):

You should just map it manually.

```
get(userId: number): Observable<IUser> {
    return this._http.get(this._getUrl).map(response => //map it to object);
}
```

Comment: I have tried that, but it doesn't work like that either. response.userId is undefined, and if I put response.UserId I get an error message since response is supposed to be of type IUser. I've attached an image in my original post at the bottom.

Comment: @halterdev,  userId is not equal UserId. you needn't use map (map is used when you received an array of user to change all the elements from the array -well you can use with an element,  but it's not necesary-), only this.user={userId:data.UserId,username:data.Username}

Comment: Right, and that will work, but it gives me the red error lines in the IDE, which I am trying to avoid. I was under the impression that this would automatically convert my response into my IUser object.